# (U)EFI boot failure after migration from Hyper-V

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair, grub-efi

My company has recently started migrating virtual machines from Microsoft Hyper-V to Proxmox VE. We have migrated one of our Generation 2 machines (Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS) using Clonezilla Live.

After the migration the machine refuses to boot at all using (U)EFI and of course won't boot with BIOS either.

We have tried many different things like manually reinstalling GRUB, copying boot files to another partition, marking a different partition as boot and even trying to convert to BIOS with MBR but all to no avail...

The last thing I have tried now is using boot-repair from an Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 live CD. This seemed to run without any issues, but after rebooting I got the following error messages:

[image]

Here's the info from boot-repair: http://paste2.org/EkkKgYgy

I would really like to know how to get this machine working again without having to install it fresh, reinstalling all the packages and restoring our data as this machine has our Icinga2 monitoring software installed on it.

P.S. the original machine in Hyper-V is still up and running.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, we found out that the files `grubx64.efi` and `MokManager.efi` were located in `\EFI\ubuntu` instead of `\EFI\Boot` so we copied them manually and the machine booted up.

Afterwards we had another small problem, we got the following message stuck in screen:

```
lvmetad is not active yet; using direct activation during sysinit
/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root: clean, 121574/7168000 files, 1115621/2865544 blocks
```

This was solved by editing the file `/etc/default/grub` with the following changes:

set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"`
and adding the line `GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="console serial"`
followed by a `sudo update-grub`.

So far everything seems to work now!